# jquery accordion menu animation transition

Tags: jquery, css, animation, slider, accordion

I am looking for a tutorial on how to reproduce an effect very similar to `www.outdatedbrowser.com`  I really like the way it animates and navigates.   Does anyone have any pointers.  Much appreciated,

Cheers,
Greg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a tutorial, but much of this (if not all) can be done using CSS transitions and animations (Google these).  For anything CSS cant do, use an animation library like TweenLite / TweenMax http://greensock.com/.